# sending parameter from JSP to PHP useing JSP:forward

Tags: java, php, javascript, html, jsp

I need to send a parameter named "Name" from JSP to an other php page.I have inserted the following code in my jsp but i don't know how to read this parameter in php.

```
<jsp:forward page="secondpage.php">
<jsp:param name="param1" value="<%= Name %>" />
</jsp:forward>
```

I would be thankfull for every answer or suggestion.

Comment: try <?php echo $_GET['param1'];?>

Comment: $_GET['param1'] : isin't it used for parameters sent through URLs?

Comment: I'm sorry i tried it but it's not working

Comment: then try <?php echo $_POST['param1'];?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `<jsp:forward>` works for resources with the current WAR. Is your PHP in the same WAR ? For URLs outside the war, you need JSTL's `<c:import>`.

Comment: No they'r not in the same WAR.Is this the correct form to use: <c:import var="Param1" url="C:/Users/dabdoubb/NetBeansProjects/PFE/web/Info_Personel.jsp"/> and then, how can i get Param1 in php? excuse me i'm a beginner.

Comment: You need to give the full URL like `<c:import url="http://www.google.com" var="data" />`. See the documentation for more details